# PowerShell containment operators with collections of objects

Tags: powershell, operators

When using the containment operators in PowerShell (e.g., -contains, -notcontains, -in) on a collection of objects (in this case, created by ActiveDirectory module commandlets) I am not observing expected results. The operators seem to fail to detect an object in the collection that I am certain is a match.

In the below example, I even use the compare-object commandlet to demonstrate that the element is indeed a match.

```
$PSVersionTable | Format-Table

$adusers_list = (get-aduser -id fooboss -properties directreports).directreports |%{ Get-ADUser -Identity $PSItem } 

$target_aduser = get-aduser -id jrw 


# This use of containing operators seems very similar to the example presented in documentation:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6#containment-operators
# Here comes the unexpected results:
$adusers_list -contains $target_aduser

$target_aduser -in $adusers_list 

#And yet...
$adusers_list |%{
    if ($_.samaccountname -eq "jrw") {
        write-output "Contrary to what the contains operators told us, here it is: $($_.samaccountname)"
        Write-output "also, compare-object says:"
        compare-object $_ $target_aduser
    }
}
```

and the output:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                      
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                      
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.145                                                                                                                                              
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                    
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                    
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.145                                                                                                                                             
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                            
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                        
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                        
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                                    


False
False
Contrary to what the contains operators told us, here it is: jrw
also, compare-object says:

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

I realize I can just loop through and manually compare a set of attributes, and I will do that if I cannot learn the correct way to use the containment operators, but I am trying to do that first.

The operator documentation does not seem to mention elements of type object specifically. It does use the term "reference value", so maybe that implies that it must be a simple data type? But if that is so, shouldn't the documentation mention that, and perhaps also PS would throw some kind of soft exception for incomparable types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing a complex object to a simple value.  You need to compare equivalent object types.  As an example to show you, change your comparison logic to:

```
($adusers_list | Select -Expand samaccountname) -contains $target_aduser.samaccountname
```

What this effectively does is turns AD User List into nothing more than a `string[]` containing the samaccountname of the users in your `$adusers_list`.  Then we compare the equivalent value (`$target_user.samaccountname`) to see if that `string`-value is contained in the compared `string[]`.

Comment: Where is the "simple value" that is getting compared? Both sides of the comparison operator are composed of type Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount (obviously a collection of them on the left), and both were generated by the same cmdlet with no additional Properties specified. Your workaround is a good one, and I'll probably use it, but I want to understand why/if I need a workaround in the first place.

Comment: There is no built-in capability that tests a complex object in a complex object collection--theres simply too many ways it would lead to false conclusions.  The answer isn't a workaround, it's describing how the operators are expecting to compare data and a way you can implement that with the existing code you offered.

Comment: I think the point about false conclusions is arguable and in fact we already have a false conclusion produced by the operator, hence my question. I think the published documentation should be clearer and the language interpreter should off a warning or exception. If no one posts some kind of definitive documentation citation or something soon, I'll be sure to accept your answer. Thank you for time and skill, thepip3r.

Comment: @Justin, this isn't a point to argue.  You're using the operator incorrectly by comparing a complex AD object to a complex AD object collection.  -contains checks for a string in a string[] or an int in an int[], not an object in an object[] or collection[].  If you want to do complex object analysis, you need to write a custom function for it.